# Migrate existing live Django site from one server to another along with user records intact

Tags: django, database-migration, digital-ocean

I have deployed a Django site on GoDaddy Django "droplet" for a while and users have been using the site to keep their records. 
Now that GoDaddy is discontinuing the service, I would like to migrate the entire site with all records intact to DigitalOcean. 
How does one go about doing this?

Comment: What is the database that you are using? Sqlite can be just copied and pasted and reused. Make sure your db structure is same. However, i would suggest you to look and dumpdata and loaddata. Check out the examples [here] (https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata)

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL so ended up using dumpdata and loaddata. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

- dump my data into a file see [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#s-dumpdata)
- stop the server
- remove all `.pyc` files
- copy paste the whole folder of the website to the destination server
- restore data using [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#s-loaddata)
- run the server

I did this 4 times without any problems (dev to test environment, test to pre-prod and pre-prod to prod).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. 
I ended up using dumpdata using command: "python manage.py dumpdata --exclude=contenttypes --exclude=auth.Permission --exclude=admin --exclude=sessions > test_fixture.json" and successfully restored in the new database using your steps. 
The only thing causing me problems was with user permissions and user groups but I bypassed those by removing those in the origin db first before dumpdata.

Answer (score 1):

The reply by Oliver is good for small sites, but big companies (or any) won't be happy if you stop the server, also some records/**sales might be done between the time you dump and the time you stop the server**

I think this would be better but **I'm unsure**:

- make a new database and make it sync with the old one, whenever old db changes changes should be synced to the new db (I know for example postgres has a feature that triggers some kind of alerts on creations/updates, this is indeed the hardest step and needs quite a lot of research to pull it off, both databases must be on sync)
- upload the new(copy) page next to the new database connected to it
- modify the DNS records to point to the new server, traffic will organically move to the new server, at some point you might have people making database updates on both servers so it is important that the sync goes both ways
- take the first web-page's server down, cut the database syncing and remove old
  page and old database
- remove the pipe/method that was letting you sync the
  new db with the old one

Comment: Your proposal implies a multi-master sertup for the database servers, which is risky and difficult, and usually undoable without stopping. Depending on the database used you may not be able to do it this way